# C#, How to make overload methods share <summary> tag

Tags: c#, methods, overloading, summary, xml-documentation

I'm developing a small class, with my overload methods, like following:

```
/// <summary>
/// some description about myMethod
/// </summary>
/// <param name="arg1"></param>
/// <param name="arg2"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public string myMethod(string arg1, string arg2) { };
public string myMethod(string arg1){};
```

The problem is that the method which take one argument does not show the description in  tag. Should I separately add the same summary tag to the second method? I think it is a little annoying, because the myMethod description should has the same  tag description, although the parameter description can vary.

Is there a way to make overload methods share one  description?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't.   Sorry.

Comment: How would this happen? The tooltip for a method with 1 argument would display 3. That's just confusing, I'm afraid you'll have to duplicate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the method names are same, but they can have different implementation and can do different things. Hence you need to provide separate summary for each of them.